# Select2.js plugin prepends instead of appends container the selected element

Tags: jquery-plugins

I'm using the jQuery plugin [Select2.js v3.2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/index.html) and it seems to insert the `select2-container` before the element instead of after the element. This is causing some code that assumes a previous sibling to break. Is there an "append after" option to initialize the container so I know it will always append after the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to be a way to specify whether to insert the `select2-container` before or after the element. The way I see it you have a few options:

- Modify the Select2.js source to insert the container after the element. [Line 595](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/blob/master/select2.js) change `.before(this.container);` to `.after(this.container);`.
- It's not clear from your question as to which code "assumes a previous sibling". If it is your code that is what you should change. If it is not your code you can try to locate and resolve that. I was unable to locate any such assumptions in the Select2.js source.
- After initializing the select2 you can follow up by moving the created elements to the desired location in the DOM. You may want to hide these elements until they are initialized. You should also test this to make sure it doesn't break the Select2.js plugin.

  ```
  $('.select2-container').each(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.elementSelector').first().after($(this));
  });
  ```

Be aware that modifying the Select2.js source will make upgrading that library in the future more painful (depending of your level of comfort/expertise). I recommend that you be completely sure the problem is not in your code before modifying the plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the response. All valid points. For your second bullet point it is my code (code someone else wrote but I can change). I think I'll stick with Chosen instead of Select2 at this point. The reason for trying out Select2 in the first place was dynamic width.

Comment: You're welcome. Not having used either library, I'm not exactly sure what you mean by dynamic width. I'd be willing to bet there is a way to accomplish it with custom js or css.

Comment: Essentially, Select2 is a fork of Chosen with a lot more features. Some of those features are really just mimicking the native select element. When I say dynamic width I mean you can set a width of 100% with Select2 but not with Chosen.